# problem with sending a float number in a stream in vivado_hls

Tags: c++, image-processing, vivado-hls

I am trying to do a simple image processing filter where the pixel values will be divided by half to reduce the intensity and I am trying to develop the hardware for the same. hence I am using ***vivado hls*** to generate the IP. As explained here https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/Float-numbers-with-hls-stream/m-p/942747 to send floating numbers in a hls stream , an union needs to be used and I did the same. However, the results don't seem to be matching for the red and green components of the image whereas it is matching for the blue component of the image. It is a very simple algorithm where a pixel value will be divided by half.

I have been trying to resolve it but I am not able to see where the problem is. I have attached all the files below, can someone can help me resolve it??

```
////header file
#include "ap_fixed.h"
#include "hls_stream.h"

typedef union {
    unsigned int i;
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
} conv;

typedef hls::stream <unsigned int> Stream_t;

void ftest(Stream_t& Sin,Stream_t& Sout);



////testbench
#include "stream_check_h.hpp"


int main()
{
Mat img_rev = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/output_fwd_v3.png");//(256x512)
Mat final_img(img_rev.rows,img_rev.cols,CV_8UC3);
Mat ref_img(img_rev.rows,img_rev.cols,CV_8UC3);

    Stream_t S1,S2;
    int err_r = 0;
    int err_g = 0;
    int err_b = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<512;j++)
        {
        conv c;
        c.r = (float)img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        c.g = (float)img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
        c.b = (float)img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
        S1 << c.i;
    }
    }


        ftest(S1,S2);
    conv c;
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<512;j++)
            {
                S2 >> c.i;
                final_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=(unsigned char)c.r;
                final_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1]=(unsigned char)c.g;
                final_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2]=(unsigned char)c.b;

                ref_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = (unsigned char)(((float)img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0])/2.0);
                ref_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = (unsigned char)(((float)img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1])/2.0);
                ref_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = (unsigned char)(((float)img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2])/2.0);
            }
        }
    Mat diff;
    cout<<diff;

    diff= abs(final_img-ref_img);
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<512;j++)
                {
                    if((int)diff.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] > 0)
                        {
                        err_r++;
                        cout<<"expected value: "<<(int)ref_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]<<", final_value: "<<(int)final_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]<<", actual value:"<<(int)img_rev.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]<<endl;
                        }
                    if((int)diff.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] > 0)
                        err_g++;
                    if((int)diff.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] > 0)
                        err_b++;

                }
            }
cout<<"number of errors: "<<err_r<<", "<<err_g<<", "<<err_b;
    return 0;
}

////core
#include "stream_check_h.hpp"


void ftest(Stream_t& Sin,Stream_t& Sout)
{
    conv cin,cout;


    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<512;j++)
        {
            Sin >> cin.i;
            cout.r = cin.r/2.0 ;
            cout.g = cin.g/2.0 ;
            cout.b = cin.b/2.0 ;
            Sout << cout.i;
        }

    }

}
```

when I debugged, it showed that the blue components of the pixels are matching. for one red pixel  it showed me the following:

```
expected value: 22, final_value: 14, actual value:45
```

and the total errors for red, green, and blue are:

```
number of errors: 126773, 131072, 0
```

I am not able to see why it is going wrong for red and green. I posted here hoping a fresh set of eyes would help my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a 32bit-wide stream with 3 RGB pixels 8bit unsigned (CV_8U3). I believe the problem with the union type in your case is the *overlapping* of its *three* members (not just like the one float value in the example you cite). This means that by doing the division, you're actually doing it over the *whole* 32bit data you're receiving.

I possible workaround I quickly cam up with would be to cast the unsigned int you're getting from the stream into an `ap_uint<32>` type, then chop it in the R, G, B chunks (with the `range()` method) and divide. Finally, assemble back the result and stream it back.

```
unsigned int packet;
Sin >> packet;
ap_uint<32> packet_uint32 = *((ap_uint<32>*)&packet); // casting (not elegant, but works)
ap_int<8> b = packet_uint32.range(7, 0);
ap_int<8> g = packet_uint32.range(15, 8);
ap_int<8> r = packet_uint32.range(23, 16); // In case they are in the wrong bit range/order, just flip the r, g, b assignements
b /= 2;
g /= 2;
r /= 2;
packet_uint32.range(7, 0) = b;
packet_uint32.range(15, 8) = g;
packet_uint32.range(23, 16) = r;
packet = packet_uint32.to_int();
Sout << packet;
```

NOTE: I've reused the same variables in the code above: HLS shouldn't complain about it and come out with a good RTL anyway. In case it shouldn't, just create new ones.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, The solution you suggested is for a 8 bit unsignigned int, I want to send the r,g and b values in terms of floating point.

Comment: You will anyway transfer 3x8bits, which can be manipulated as unsigned ints (or chars actually). Once in the accelerator, they can be "interpreted" as floats. However, there's no standard for representing 8bit floating points numbers. If you really need to represent real values, cast them to the HLS ap_fixed type (set its bitwidth to 8).

Comment: What I mean is: floats are just a way to interpret/see/process a bunch of bits (being 32 or 64 (or 16 half if the compiler supports it, as Vivado HLS does)). In this case, and in the code you propose, the transfering packets doesn't require to be float, but to be interpreted as floats once in the accelerator.

If you have tried my solution, does it work now?